# Curve - non singular curve and its genus

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

Help me please with this problem:$ X \subset \mathbb{P}^{2}$
defined as $x^{3}y+y^{3}z+z^{3}x=0$

1.Prove X - non singular curve and find its genus.
2.Prove X - maximal curve over $F_{8}$ field, and find all points of X.

Thanks a lot!